# Imported polygon from Google Earth is not being merged

Tags: qgis, gps, mapping

I'm new to QGIS. I need to merge two polygon that I have imported from Google Earth (.kml) but when I try to do so I am getting an error message

> Not enough features selected: The merge tool requires at least two selected features

Is there any remedy?

[image: please See this screen shot]

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you're trying to do (which tools you're using, what commands you give the tools, relation of layers/features, etc.). Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/370785/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: I have Imported two polygon from a KML file and now I want to merge it. for that I have selected these two polygon as shows in picture. and then Edit -> Merge selcected features. But I am getting Error Message "Not enough features selected: The merge tool requires at least two selected features"

Comment: are the two polygons in the same layer? merge won't work across layers.

Comment: Also, editing KML is afaik not possible in QGIS, only import/export.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to convert the KML to shapefile first. I think QGIS has this feature (right click->Save as)

Comment: actually, GeoPackages are prefered for this sort of thing these days.